# How to setup Smart Mailbox to exclude messages only in Gmail's Archive?

Tags: mail.app, gmail, ventura

Running Mail.app on Ventura 13.4.1
I use Gmail and have about a dozen Gmail Labels I use for different types of email.

I'm trying to setup a Smart Mailbox in Mail.app that will show me all the emails from Today that are either in my Inbox, or one of the other Labels I've set, but NOT show me emails I've sent to Gmail's archive, and no longer have one of the custom labels assigned to it.

Mail.app's Smart Mailbox does not allow tiered Any/All statements, so I cannot choose All messages from Today, and Any from any of a number of selected mailboxes.
Suggestions?